# Custom YAML deserializer with Jackson Library

Tags: java, json, jackson, yaml

I was wondering how I can implement the custom deserializer for the YAML with Jackson Library. I went to Google and found information that I can simply extend from the `StdDeserializer` class and then add my custom deserializer to the `SimpleModule`. However, I have a doubt about the signature of the `deserialize` method of the `StdDeserializer` class that provides a `JsonParser` argument and it confuses me a bit. So the question is: when I implement the custom deserializer for the YAML will Jackson at first convert YAML to the JSON and provide me the JSON data or not?

Actually, me deserializer is working fine, but if Jackson do the conversion beetwen JSON and YAML it is not acceptable for me.

Comment: What is it you need to do? Do you have a JSON structure that has one field that contains YAML? Or is your entire structure YAML? Because in case of the latter, use `jackson-dataformat-yaml`: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-yaml